# How can a make a bottom border on these columns?

Tags: css, multiple-columns

Here is my code:

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

#column1 {
  background-color: #e67e22;
}

#column2 {
  background-color: #3498db;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" id="column1">
    <h2>THIS IS A TEST</h2>
    <h2>THIS IS A TEST DESCRIPTION - THIS IS A TEST DESCRIPTION - THIS IS A TEST DESCRIPTION - THIS IS A TEST DESCRIPTION</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="column" id="column2">
    <h2>THIS IS A TEST</h2>
    <h2>THIS IS A TEST DESCRIPTION - THIS IS A TEST DESCRIPTION - THIS IS A TEST DESCRIPTION - THIS IS A TEST DESCRIPTION</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

How would I be able to create a bottom border without removing margin? When I try using padding, the columns dont have a space in-between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a bottom border like this:

```
.row > div {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

This basically targets every `div` that is a direct child of the class `.row`.  You can also adjust the colour of the border, its thickness and the type of line drawn.  See options here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border

**See demo below:**

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

#column1 {
  background-color: #e67e22;
}

#column2 {
  background-color: #3498db;
}

/* you can adjust the thickness and colour as desired*/
.row>div {
  border-bottom: 3px solid black; 
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" id="column1">
    <h2>THIS IS A TEST</h2>
    <h2>THIS IS A TEST DESCRIPTION - THIS IS A TEST DESCRIPTION - THIS IS A TEST DESCRIPTION - THIS IS A TEST DESCRIPTION</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="column" id="column2">
    <h2>THIS IS A TEST</h2>
    <h2>THIS IS A TEST DESCRIPTION - THIS IS A TEST DESCRIPTION - THIS IS A TEST DESCRIPTION - THIS IS A TEST DESCRIPTION</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```